# htaccess internal error code 500

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, rewritemap

when I try to make 301 redirect I get an internal error code 500:

```
Rewriterule ^categoy/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)? product_detail.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2&product=$4 [QSA,NC]
```

RewriteMap fiel:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

any suggestion why I get this error ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you get a 500 error from Apache, Apache will make a note of *why* it gave you that error in your `error_log`, wherever that is configured to go. Refer to the error message in that log to find out what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

RewriteMap directives aren't allowed within .htaccess file.
It should be written in Apache's configuration file httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

okay... lets get some things straight.

```
Rewriterule ^categoy/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)? product_detail.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2&product=$4 [QSA,NC]
```

theres a lot of redundant stuff in here as for example NC does case insensitive matching anyway..
i formatted your code a bit:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z] 
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

which rule are you talking about now? from your title (301) i think the second one.
your rewritecondition looks weird.
but however the most common reason for an error 500 in relation to rewrite rules is lacking permissions. make sure you do `AllowOverride All` in your server config or move your rules there (which gives more performance than in htaccess files)

Comment: thanks alot Joe Hopfgartner will check and get back to you